# How to make a button with an icon in Android?

Tags: android

I didn't expect this to be so hard. I want to make a button, like a normal button, but instead of text I would like it to show an icon (SVG).

I have tried:

- Setting `icon` draws a tiny icon at the left edge of the button
- Using `ImageButton` instead of `Button` gives me `scaleType=fitCenter` but doesn't look like a button any more (it's just a gray rectangle)
- Setting `background` distorts the icon because it doesn't keep the aspect ratio *and* it doesn't look like a button any more
- Using an emoji as `text` works but limits me to the range of available emojis

Comment: You might try some experiments with the "Implementing an icon-only toggle button" instructions in [the Material Design button documentation](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button). While that information is focused on toggle buttons -- which probably is not what you want -- you might get some ideas from how they style the individual buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the styling stuff at all. It probably has to do with the fact that `ImageButton` is a subclass of `ImageView` and not of `Button`. The docs for `Button` actually talk about "buttonStyle" and "the system's default button background" but I don't know how all that fits together.

Comment: Then again the docs for `ImageButton` say "By default, an `ImageButton` looks like a regular `Button`" which is clearly wrong as anyone can verify simply by dragging a Button and an ImageButton into a layout.

Comment: Regarding that weird look despite the documentation saying otherwise I have opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502692/make-android-imagebutton-look-like-button).

Answer (score 0):

You can go for this option:

- Setting icon draws a tiny icon at the left edge of the button

Then:

- **To control the size:** use `app:iconSize` attribute.
- **To control the horizontal displacement to the right**:

  1. Adjust negative padding to `app:iconPadding`
  2. Adjust positive padding to `android:paddingStart`

Be careful as adjusting to high values, can intersect the icon with the Button text.

Here is a sample:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:text="Alert\nReceived"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:icon="@drawable/alarm"
    app:iconPadding="-20dp"
    app:iconSize="70dp" />
```

[image]

**Update**

> so it's unclear how to make the icon centered. By the way, there is no text, I want a button with just an icon. –

As it's a no-text button with just an icon:

The icon can be centered by using `app:iconGravity="textEnd"` it aligns the icon to end of the text (witch is by default at the center).
This also can be used with `textStart` as there is no text already.

There is a default icon padding that you can remove as well, so also set `app:iconPadding="0dp"`, and remove the `android:paddingStart` attribute

Comment: Two issues: 1. Now that I adjusted the `iconSize` I can see that the image is distorted. I guess in your example it only works because the clock is square. 2. `app:iconPadding` seems to have no effect and `android:paddingStart` doesn't accept percentages, so it's unclear how to make the icon centered. By the way, there is no text, I want a button with just an icon.

Comment: @AndreKR For centering the icon, I just updated the answer. Regarding the distortion, it is highly coupled to the icon; you could try different types of icons and see

Comment: You can try the `MaterialButton` instead; not sure if it has something to offer to the distortion

Comment: When I look at the button in the debugger, it says it actually *is* a `MaterialButton`. No idea what is going on.