# Make Android ImageButton look like Button

Tags: android

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) for `ImageButton` says:

> By default, an `ImageButton` looks like a regular `Button`

This is obviously wrong because when I put both into a layout:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
```

and run it, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The `Button` has a color and a shadow while the `ImageButton` is just a gray rectangle (with round corners I think).

Unfortunately I don't understand at all how styles work. My main question though is how do I need to change the ImageButton's configuration to *actually* make it look like a regular `Button`.

Comment: This answer shows how widgets styling works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222858/android-default-button-style/#13223330

Answer (score 0):

Are you using material design? Your Button does not look like the **regular** button that default style is `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button`, but like the **material** button, which default style is `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`. If you set the style of the Button to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button`, you will see it looks the same as the ImageButton with default style `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton`

This is `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button`, you can see that it has been expanded on the basis of `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button`:

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@empty</item>
<item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
<item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_left</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_right</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_top</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_bottom</item>
<item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
<item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
<item name="android:insetTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
<item name="android:insetBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
<item name="android:stateListAnimator" ns2:ignore="NewApi">@animator/mtrl_btn_state_list_anim</item>
<item name="cornerRadius">@null</item>
<item name="elevation">@dimen/mtrl_btn_elevation</item>
<item name="iconPadding">@dimen/mtrl_btn_icon_padding</item>
<item name="iconTint">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
<item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_ripple_color</item>
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
<item name="shapeAppearance">?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent</item>
</style>
```

So, you can customize a new style for ImageButton, and then add those new style attributes of material button to the custom style (mainly `cornerRadius`, `elevation`, and `rippleColor`)

or set the button's style to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button`, while will also make the ImageButton looks like the Button :P

Comment: "Are you using material design?", what does that mean? This is just what buttons look like when I open a fresh install of Android Studio and create a "Basic Activity" project. I didn't know there was a choice.

Comment: Check the module build.gradle dependencies, if there is "implementation  'com.google.android.material:material:X.X.X'", that means you are using material design, it will change the default style of some widgets to material style

Comment: Yes, it says `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`.